# Why does voltage fall to zero in this power mosfet switching basis once current reaches a certain level?

Tags: power, mosfet

I have this simple circuit[image: Mosfet in a switching power pole].

This is a converter, where the power-pole is made as a power mosfet transistor plus a diode.

I did not get the Turn-on behaviour as shown here [image: Turn-on behaviour]

In particular, I don't get why, once the MOSFET current reaches I0, the MOSFET voltage falls. Should it not stay to a value Vds? Why does Vds go to zero?

Comment: What did you get?

Comment: I simply don't get why, from a theoretical point of view, vds is equal to zero. Should not the transistor have a resistance? Also assuming the resistance equal to zero, should I not still see Vin ? It is a really stupid question, but I don't get why vds goes to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Vds goes to zero because it can - it is not held at some constant voltage by a perfect voltage generator (Vin) - it is in series with a constant current generator (Io) and once Io is reached, the voltage across the device will fall to nearly zero.